# Is it possible to have a method that takes a generic Comparable?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, merge, comparable

I'm implementing a merge sort algorithm in Java for school.

It should be able to take any object that is comparable.

I created a static mergeSort(ArrayList input) method but apparently I cannot cast ArrayList or ArrayList into ArrayList even though they both implement comparable.

How can I represent an ArrayList of Comparable data ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use generics. Something like `public static <T extends Comparable<T>> ArrayList<T> mergeSort(ArrayList<T> list) {...`

Then you can use `T` as a type. Like `T a = list.get(0);` and you can do `(a.compareTo(b))`.